# How to debug an ApolloServer's context function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apollo, apollo-server, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to follow the GraphQL tutorial (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers/), but I'm getting an error in the playground when I try to book a trip, with a stack trace starting like this:

```
 "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null",
            "    at UserAPI.bookTrips (/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Scratch/fullstack-tutorial/start/server/src/datasources/user.js:35:38)",
```

[image]

In `src/index.js`, the `ApolloServer` (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/) is defined with an asynchronous `context()` function like so:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');
const typeDefs = require('./schema');
const { createStore } = require('./utils');
const resolvers = require('./resolvers');

const LaunchAPI = require('./datasources/launch');
const UserAPI = require('./datasources/user');
const isEmail = require('isemail');

const store = createStore();

const server = new ApolloServer({
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    debugger;
    const auth = (req.headers && req.headers.authorization) || '';
    const email = Buffer.from(auth, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    if (!isEmail.validate(email)) return { user: null };

    const users = await store.users.findOrCreate({ where: { email }});
    const user = users && users[0] ? users[0] : null;

    return { user: { ...user.dataValues }};
  },
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  dataSources: () => ({
    launchAPI: new LaunchAPI(),
    userAPI: new UserAPI({ store })
  })
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

Since the error I'm seeing is the result of the context's `user` being `null`, I would like to step through the `context()` method to inspect the headers and see whether it contains a valid (encoded) email; as you can see I've set a `debugger` breakpoint at the start of that function.

However, when I run `node inspect src/index.js`, I immediately enter the debugger for an `IntrospectionQuery`:

[image]

If I press the 'Resume script execution' button, I just get back immediately to the same breakpoint.

Does this have something to do with the fact that `context()` is an `async` function? How can I step through the `context()` method with the debugger?

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I just debugged it using `console.log()` commands. I had accidentally put the `authorization` in the 'Query Variables' section rather than the 'HTTP Headers' one. Moving it to 'HTTP Headers' produces the desired result:

[image]